# Windows Phone 7 States

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I know about tombstoning stuff any how to save the states of your application but my question is this regarding states.

Let's say I have a page that have 5 buttons. Whenever I click a button the button can be either visible or hidden. How do I save the current state or the saved state of my page? Let's say if I exit my application and loaded the 5 buttons again one button should be hidden.

I tried saving a variable state value in an IsolatedStorageFile and retrieve it when the Page is loaded in loaded event but I figured out that it's too tedious for the processor to do a lot of things just for saving a state.

Another solution I thought of is when the Loaded event is fired, I will statically declare an if else statements and manually declare the Visibility of the button.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do the same thing when the page/app is exited normally and when it's tombstoned? The default expected behaviour is that when launching the app after exiting (via the back button) the app will be in it's default state. When returning from a tombstoned state the app should (as far as is appropriate) be displayed to the user in exactly the same way as when the page/app was tombstoned.
Of course you may have differing needs but I wanted highlight the standard behaviour.

If you want to store state while tombstoned, the convention is to use the OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo events to store details in the State object.

There is a good example of how to do this on MSDN: [How to: Preserve and Restore Page State for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967548%28VS.92%29.aspx)

If you want to preserve state across all executions of your app then you will need to use IsolatedStorage to store the details in a persistent location. Where and when you read and write the data will depend on where the data you need to persist is located.
If it's at an applicaiton level you may be able to use the application level events (Launching, Activated, Closing & Deactivated). If you have state data at page level it's probably be better to do it in the page level (Loaded/Unloaded or NavigatedFrom/To as appropriate).

If you want to store state across all executions of the application you probably need to look at both of the above options.

Comment: Not really exited but when the user navigates away from that page and back. Of course the initial values of that page will be loaded. If I use the documentation of MSDN, I believe it will only store the state of the page while the app is running but if it exited it goes back to the initial values,, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` namespace is fine for this kind of behaviour, check it out [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickyt/archive/2010/08/12/windows-phone-application-model-navigation-and-saving-state.aspx)
Also check out this article on how to do what you are asking.

[Saving Applications States](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickyt/archive/2010/08/12/windows-phone-application-model-navigation-and-saving-state.aspx)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. If I used IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSetting will it save even the current values of my controls? Like visibility